# Я использую ActiveForm и DatePicker от kartik, пожно ли привязать поле с DatePicker к v-model?

Tags: vue.js, yii2, activeform

Вот код который выводит поле:

```
$this->form->field($model, 'birthday')->widget(
                DatePicker::class, [
                    'name' => 'birthday_input',
                    'options' => ['placeholder' => 'ДД.ММ.ГГГГ'],
                    'pluginOptions' => [
                        'autoclose' => true,
                        'format' => 'dd.mm.yyyy',
                        'todayHighlight' => true
                    ]
                ]
            )
```

Возможно ли его привязать к данным во vue с помощью v-model, как например тут:

```
$this->form->field($model, 'surname')->textInput(['maxlength' => true, 'v-model' => 'surname']);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$this->form->field($model, 'birthday')->widget(
                DatePicker::class, [
                    'name' => 'birthday_input',
                    'options' => ['placeholder' => 'ДД.ММ.ГГГГ', 'v-model' => 'birthday', 'v-on:change' => 'manualInputData'],
                    'pluginOptions' => [
                        'autoclose' => true,
                        'format' => 'dd.mm.yyyy',
                        'todayHighlight' => true
                    ]
                ]
            );
```

Comment: Ваш ответ можно улучшить с помощью дополнительной информации. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] для добавления подробностей, например, цитат или документации, чтобы другие могли подтвердить правильность вашего ответа. Вы можете найти дополнительную информацию о том, как писать хорошие ответы [в Справке](/help/how-to-answer).